# How to set custom height for the primefaces fieldset container?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In the code, there is a select one menu which is getting hidden in the fieldset container. Is there a way to ***increase*** the ***fieldset*** container `height` so that the menu is fully visible?

- Here is the code for the fieldset.

  ```
   <p:fieldset legend="Name" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="font-size: 5px;" id="fieldSetId">
  ```

Is there any attributes I can set to expand the bottom margin of this fieldset?

Comment: For the exact solution I need to see your page code, but since it seems a simple problem, have you tried adding style="height:30px" (changing size as needed) to your fieldset (or line-height)

Comment: Start playing with CSS in the browser developer tool. Once you solved it there extrapolate to the JSF components

Comment: Thanks Matteo, Kukeltje. I tried setting style="margin-bottom: 68px;" to my div. But it did not expand the fieldset.

Comment: Play with the client side html... We are not clairvoyant. Get the rendered html, create a question about that html and css. Nothing PrimeFaces related untill you backport to the jsf/facelets view and it then fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the below solution worked.

Instead of changing the fieldset container attributes, I added appendTo="@(body)" to the selectonemenu tag.

Previously it was appendTo="@this" and the menu was not completely visible. It was partially hidden inside the container.

Thank you for helping Everyone!